# If I copy, modify, then submit a file in Perforce, will the copy still retain the original's history?

Tags: perforce

Suppose I have a file `A.txt` in my Perforce client workspace, which already exists on the server as `//depot/A.txt`. Now, suppose I want to make a copy of A.txt, call it `B.txt`, and make some changes to B.txt *before* I commit it to the server. I might do this like so:

```
p4 integrate A.txt B.txt
p4 edit B.txt
vim B.txt
p4 submit
```

Will Perforce remember that B.txt started out as a copy of A.txt? For example, if I run `p4 filelog B.txt`, will it show that //depot/B.txt was originally branched from //depot/A.txt ?

(Actually, I already know the answer, but it was not so easy to figure out without actually trying it completely, thanks to `p4`'s characteristically confusing output. So I figure I'll ask the question so that someone can provide an answer for the record.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer, for the record, is yes. Remember to use the `-i` ("inherited history") flag on `p4 filelog`.